# Mocking a class with no interface or virtual methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I want to test a method with following signature.

```
int SomeMethod(List<Employee> employees)
```

Here are the related classes

```
public class Employee
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

}

public class Address
{
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

How can I mock the `List<Employee>` as an input to SomeMethod? Note that Employee and Address classes has no interface or virtual method.

Comment: Your classes are models. Why you mocking models? They don't have any functionalities.

Comment: Can you please provide your test case adn method which you want to test?

Comment: That's correct, These are model but let's say SomeMethod has some business logic that I want to test. Is this not a good scenario to test for?

Comment: If your method doesn't any dependencies of functionalities of  Employee and Address you don't need to mock them. As I see Address and Employee are without functionalities, than you are OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to test method with following signature `int SomeMethod(List<Employee> employees)` you don't need to mock `Employee`!

You need to create `List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()`, pass to method and verify result!

`Employee` and `Address` are models without any functionalities and you don't need to mock them!

Here are two thoughts about your case:

1. You can legally call `new Employee()` or `new Address()` in your method because that code is **testable**! Creating new instances of models doesn't execute external dependency.
2. It will be problem to call `new Employee()` or `new Address()` only if they have functionalities. In that case you will execute real dependency which is maybe not testable! Example, if `Employee`  or `Address` communicate with database it is not testable because it will connect to real database when test is executed. Than you need to create mock to avoid database connection.

Answer (score 2):

Without an interface or common base class between Employee and your mock object you cannot pass any object except for Employee.

If you have the ability to, I would suggest creating an Interface for your employee class & mock class to both implement. Then you would just change your method parameter to accept the interface instead of Employee directly.